# How can i get Max Date in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following linq expression to compare users parameter to Max(EndDate) field?. I have multiple EndDate's but i want to get the last one.

Here is
Product 1

```
 EndDate

2018-09-30 23:59:59.000
2019-09-30 23:59:59.000
```

Product 2

```
 EndDate


2019-09-30 23:59:59.000
2019-12-31 23:59:59.000
```

When user enter 09/2019  I need to return only Product 1 since the Max(EndDate) == the value entered by the user which is `09/2009` in MM/yyyy format, currently it displays both product 1 & product 2.

In my model i have `checkBillingMonth` as bool

```
public bool checkBillingMonth { get; set; }
```

Here my linq expression looks like this but it return both prodcut 1 and product 2

```
var billingProductList = Context.Product.AsNoTracking()
        .Select(p => new ProductDTO 
         {
          checkBillingMonth = p.Billing
          .Any(b => b.EndDate.Month == request.FromDate.Month &&
               b.EndDate.Year == request.FromDate.Year)
         }).ToList();
```

How can i modify the above linq expression to get Max(EndDate) and compare to request.FromDate?

Comment: You're mixing Linq-to-Entities with Linq-to-Objects - this probably will give you a suboptimal query, potentially loading your entire table into memory.

Comment: Also the code you've posted has invalid syntax - you're missing braces and dots.

Comment: What is `ProductDTO` meant to represent? (Why does it have a property named `checkBillingMonth `? This is a very strange domain model...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code.

```
    var billingProductList = Context.Product.AsNoTracking()
            .Select(p => new ProductDTO 
             {
              checkBillingMonth = GetCheckBillingMonth(p.Invoices, request.FromDate) 
        // I'm not sure why you were having the condition related to min date
             }).ToList();
```

Private method:

```
 private bool GetCheckBillingMonth(List<Invoice> invoices, DateTime fromDate)
 {
     if (invoices == null || invoices.Count == 0) return false;

     var latestInvoiceEndDate = invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.EndDate).FirstOrDefault()?.EndDate;        
     return latestInvoiceEndDate != null && latestInvoiceEndDate.Month == fromDate.Month && latestInvoiceEndDate.Year == fromDate.Year;        
 }
```

Comment: Yes, create a private function and move this code inside that. Now you can call the function to determine the required value. I hope I have answered your question. Let me know if you need any other details

Comment: @mjwills, modified the code to call OrderByDescending only once.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question properly, you want to compare to the last invoice? Then you should flip your primary result set from Product to Invoice. Filter the latest invoices. Then select the related product details.

```cs
Context.Invoice
   .AsNoTracking()
   .Where(i => i.EndDate == i.Product.Invoices.Max(i2 => i2.EndDate))
   .Select(i => new ProductDTO{
      checkBillingMonth = i.EndDate.Month == request.FromDate.Month &&
               i.EndDate.Year == request.FromDate.Year && 
               !request.FromDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue)),
      // plus other properties from i.Product
   });
;
```